# Relationship between molar internal energy change and molar enthalpy change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> A thick-walled insulated metal chamber contains ni moles of helium at high pressure
> $P_i$ It is connected through a valve with a large, almost empty gasholder in which the
> pressure is maintained at a constant value $P'$, very nearly atmospheric. The valve is
> opened slightly, and the helium flows slowly and adiabatically into the gasholder
> until the pressure on the two sides of the valve is equalized. Prove that
>
> $$\frac{n_f}{n_i}=\frac{h'-u_i}{h'-u_f}$$
>
> where $n_f$= number of moles of helium left in the chamber,
> $u_i$ = initial molar internal energy of helium in the chamber,
> $u_f$ = final molar internal energy of helium in the chamber, and
> $h'= u' + P' v'$ (where $u'$ molar internal energy of helium in the gasholder;
> $v' $ molar volume of helium in the gasholder).

What I tried was $dQ =0$ as it's adiabatic so $n_fu_f-n_iu_i$=W ,
Where as to my intuition one component of work would be work done against $P'$ pressure that is $P'v'$ and other the internal energy $n_fu'$ . But work has more component than this as the proof is not coming. Can anyone please help where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think the change in internal energy that I have found out isn't completely correct as i think its the change in one chamber only(the initial one).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the equation you were given, you would have $$n_fu_f-n_iu_i=-h'(n_i-n_f)$$This implies that the enthalpy of the gas leaving the chamber is equal to h' in the gas holder, which is clearly not the case.  Even though the enthalpy of the stream leaving the chamber is equal to the enthalpy of the stream entering the gas holder, this does not mean that the enthalpy in the gas holder represents the enthalpy of the gas leaving the chamber.  In my judgment, whoever devised this problem is very confused about the proper application of the open system version of the 1st law.

For the chamber in this case, the correct equation should read $$d(nu)=hdn$$where h is the molar enthalpy within the chamber.

Comment: Thanks @Chet Miller. Just one clarification.,.               Can we think the equation as LHS representing decrease in energy of initial chamber (only internal energy of gas is there) which is equal to RHS that is increase in energy of gasholder(which contains internal energy of gas holder and pressure volume energy ($P'v'$) ) then the equation will follow energy conservation or 1st law of thermodynamics? I don't know if I am right, it just came to my mind.  The book tell it to be illustration of throttling process.(zemansky and ditman).

Comment: Are you familiar with the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics?  If not fully familiar, get yourself a decent Thermo book like Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics or Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics (available online).  In the equation I wrote, the RHS represents the internal energy of the gas leaving the chamber  through the valve plus the P-V work done to push the exiting gas into the valve.